# ImportError: No Module named simplejson

Tags: python, unix

I'm trying to run a command to install bespinclient on my Windows laptop but every time I execute the command `python bootstrap.py --no-site-packages`, I get an error saying:

> ImportError: No module named
>   simplejson

I'm using Mozilla build tools to run these Linux commands.

Comment: So... install simplejson? Or was that not the question?

Answer (score 92):

That means you must install [`simplejson`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/). On newer versions of python, it was included by default into python's distribution, and renamed to `json`. So if you are on python 2.6+ you should change all instances of `simplejson` to `json`.

For a quick fix you could also edit the file and change the line:

```
import simplejson
```

to:

```
import json as simplejson
```

and hopefully things will work.

Answer (score 9):

@noskio is correct... it just means that `simplejson` isn't found on your system and you need to install it for Python older than 2.6. one way is to use the [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) `easy_install` tool. with it, you can install it as easily as: `easy_install simplejson`

UPDATE (Feb 2014): this is probably old news to many of you, but pip is a more modern tool that works in a similar way (i.e., `pip install simplejson`), only it can also *uninstall* apps.

Comment: Despite what nosklo said about newer versions of python... pip install simplejson worked perfectly.

Comment: Oh yes, for sure, that will still work because simplejson still exists (It's the externally-maintained name.) The only "problem" for those on 2.6+ is that now you have two (nearly) identical libraries on your hard drive.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu/Debian, you can install it with `apt-get install python-simplejson`

Comment: Whilst it can be troublesome to set it up, it is possible to use pip on windows.  I know it can work as I've got pip running on my windows machine.

Here are a couple of starting points:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows
http://arunrocks.com/guide-to-install-python-or-pip-on-windows/

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes there is permission errors. Try:

```
sudo pip install simplejson
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this years later:

TL;DR check your pip version (2 vs 3)

I had this same issue and it was not fixed by running `pip install simplejson` despite pip insisting that it was installed. Then I realized that I had both python 2 and python 3 installed.

```
> python -V
Python 2.7.12
> pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Installing with the correct version of pip is as easy as using `pip2`:

```
> pip2 install simplejson
```

and then python 2 can `import simplejson` fine.