# Can't find simplejson but when trying to install it says it is there?

Tags: python, osx-yosemite, odoo, simplejson

When I try to compile I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named simplejson
```

So I tried:

```
pip install simplejson
```

And I am getting:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplejson in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

I tried uninstalling it and installing it again and the same error.

I am running `python 2.7.9` on `OS Yosemite`

Any idea what can I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope there are no multiple python instance running i n your machine

Comment: They shouldn't be, but how can I check?

Comment: $> which python and $> which pip

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get your simplejson installation working, you can alternatively use the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library included in by default in Python 2.6+. If you're not concerned with small speed differences or backwards compatibility issues, the JSON library should be adequate and provides the same API. For more info on the differences between json and simplejson, check out [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712791/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-simplejson-python-modules)

You can also satisfy current dependencies on simplejson by changing your import statement from

```
import simplejson
```

to

```
import json as simplejson
```

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41031835/2674563). The short version is to make sure the version of pip you're using (2 vs 3) is the same as the version of python you're using. The commands you want are

```
pip2 install simplejson
```

if you're using python 2 and

```
pip3 install simplejson
```

if you're using python 3.

---

The full answer as mirrored from the link:

I had this same issue and it was not fixed by running `pip install simplejson` despite pip insisting that it was installed. Then I realized that I had both python 2 and python 3 installed.

```
> python -V
Python 2.7.12
> pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Installing with the correct version of pip is as easy as using `pip2`:

```
> pip2 install simplejson
```

and then python 2 can `import simplejson` fine.