# ImportError: No module named lxml on Mac OSX 10.11

Tags: python, pip, lxml

I just bought a new Mac Book Pro with OSX 10.11 `El Capitan`.

I'm running `Google App Engine` Launcher python for local dev, which is where I see this in the logs when it reaches `import lxml`.

```
"ImportError: No module named lxml"
```

I followed the instructions from the [lxml website](http://lxml.de/installation.html#using-lxml-with-python-libxml2)

```
sudo pip install lxml
```

Package installs but can't be seen on path by python. I updated my path in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` with:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PATH
```

Then found this article [Installing lxml on Mac OSX (10.11) inside a virtualenv with pip](http://louistiao.me/posts/installing-lxml-on-mac-osx-1011-inside-a-virtualenv-with-pip/)

```
$ STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml
```

Again it installs but can't be found.

I even tried compiling from source and installing `macports` as it got it embedded, but still no luck.

I read the lxml team is frustrated with `OSX` and the mess with its outdated libraries and all.

**UPDATE**

In relation to the comments made, its not a app.yaml libraries declaration, and its unlikely an issue specific to GAE, as it seems more likely between python and oxs-elcapitan.

also I get this unusual message

`The directory '/Users/[username]/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.`

I tried with sudo -H but that didn't resolve the paths either.

But it does suggest the changes in 10.11 might be part of the problem.

Comment: Did you run `source ~/.bash_profile` to load the updated path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No Module named simplejson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604841/importerror-no-module-named-simplejson)

Comment: What does this have to do with appengine?

Comment: This line hints that it can be related to GAE specifically: "I'm **running _Google_App_Engine_Launcher_** python for local dev, **which is where** I see this in the logs when it reaches import lxml."

Comment: Yes, ran ` source ` to update the PATH, restarted the machine also.  Still no luck.   Also ran GAE to reset it's symlinks.  I don't think its specifically a problem with GAE, and it seem more like a fundamental path problem between python and osx 10.11

Comment: I am having the same problem with lxml and appengine. Numpy and other libraries in my app.yaml work fine. Did you find a fix?

Comment: Cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine uses it's own environment that reflects their server and does not see libraries that you've installed locally.

To see the package it should be located in the root of the project (where the app.yaml is located).

But there is also runtime provide libraries- read section "**Using Runtime-Provided Libraries with the Local Development Server**" at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Probably you would need to add to **app.yaml**:

```
libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: "2.3.5"
```

Comment: Some Python libraries (e.g. lxml) are platform-dependent and must be installed locally before you can use them with the development server.

Comment: Right, but that does not mean you should not modify the app.yaml to allow the appengine to see/use them.

Comment: He should definitely declare the library in app.yaml but if I get it right, he is not able to install the library on his computer.

Comment: This line hints that it can be related to GAE specifically: "I'm **running _Google_App_Engine_Launcher_** python for local dev, **which is where** I see this in the logs when it reaches import lxml."

Comment: It's not the libraries in the app.yaml. Specifically I have several declared.

libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: latest
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

Answer (score 0):

`STATIC_DEPS` didn't work for me (looks like the relevant FTP sites were down?), but this did the trick:

`C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libxml2:$C_INCLUDE_PATH` pip install lxml